# CruiseControl CCnet.config update

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, ccnet-config

Can anyone help me on the below issue related to CruiseControl..

I am new to cruisecontrol and I have installed CCnet for .net project deployment automation on server and made modification in CCnet.config file but still dashboard is showing default project. I have created multiple project in single CCnet.config can someone help me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

By "dashboard", do you mean the CC.Net web portal?  Do you see the same results in the CCTray?
Is it possible that your changes to ccnet.config contain mistakes?  If so, CC.Net will not load the config file.  Use CCValidator to verify your config file changes.

Comment: Thanks for replying!! there was issue with the one line which was causing problem with whole config file. After removing the line it ran fine.